# Active Directory Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, communication

I developed an asp.net application that interact with Active Directory (AD).

I use this function "User.Identity.Name.ToString()" to retrieve the login of the user logged into the application.

Inclusive team project client ask me details about the project. one of them:

Which AD interface it used?

There he is someone who know the subject could inform me and at the same time if he have a link for more information?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: the "User.Identity.Name.ToString()" is in "System.Security" Library

Answer (score 0):

when used to identify the currently logged on user the `User.Identity.Name.ToString()` line reads local context information and do not access AD directly.

if in your code you have no other function/routine/whatever accessing AD the answer should be that the software use no interface to connect to AD because it is not connecting to AD.

maybe the question is a bit broad and vague...

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not sure if your answer is the correct answer. I ll wait other answer or comment. thank you for your answer again :)